# Show MVC validation in popup

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate

I have a MVC form that uses build in client side validation, by putting the annotations on the model class and adding the unobtrusive validate Javascripts as per default MVC standards. However my requirement is that instead of a validation summary at the top of the form I want to display my messages in a popup.

The popup I'm using in this case is the bootstrap modal, since this project is based on a bootstrap design.

So how do I override the onvalidate method when submiting the form to trigger my popup to show and get the correct message to be in the popup ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The best solution I could find was to hack the jquery validation plugin, since that is what MVC is using anyway. I say hack since the plugin does not expose a method to add eventhandlers and to reinstantiate the validation is not an option. So I added the binding manually after finding what the event name is. Here is the example:

```
$("#form1").bind('invalid-form.validate', 
            function(form, validator) {
                var errors = "";
                for(var i = 0; i < validator.errorList.length; i++){
                    errors += validator.errorList[i].message+" ";
                }
                if (errors != "")alert(errors);
            }
        );
```

In my case instead of calling a Javascript alert I put the code to call my popup there.